# Heap argument must be a list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, heap

I was trying to implement a data structure to returns a value such that set (key, value, timestamp_prev) was called previously, with timestamp_prev <= timestamp.
I tried to use a min heap in python. there was a fault flagged I don't quite understand.

```
class TimeMap:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.mapping = collections.defaultdict(list)


    def set(self, key: str, value: str, timestamp: int) -> None:
        self.mapping[key].append([-timestamp, value])


    def get(self, key: str, timestamp: int) -> str :
        if not self.mapping[key]:
            return ''
        heap = heapq.heapify(self.mapping[key])
        for pre_stamp, val in heapq.heappop(heap):
            if -pre_stamp <= timestamp:
                return val
        return ''
```

A fault came out with: heap argument must be a list.

But it looks the mapping[key] returned value is a list.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `self.mapping` is defined as `collections.defaultdict(list)` does not mean that `self.mapping[key]` will return a list for every arbitrary `key`. It just means that `self.mapping[key]` will return a list for every `key` that does **not** exist will return an empty list.

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['a'] = 'not a list'
print(type(d['a']), d['a'])
```

outputs

```
<class 'str'> not a list
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But everytime I call the "set" fun to append list in list before the "get", moreover the " if not self.mapping[key]" has filtered out "None" conditions. I tried some test cases and print out mapping[key] before heapify, it is a list actually.